# Add background image to list items

Tags: html, css

I would like to add the the button image as background to the list items. Here the list items have to be horizontal and each list items should not have a gap in between.

```
<nav class="clearfix"><!-- START 'nav' -->
      <h2 class="slide-trigger">Menu <span></span></h2>
      <ul class="navigation clearfix">
        <li class="current"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
      </ul>    
      <!--a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a-->
    </nav>
```

Style:

```
nav li {float: left; list-style: none; font-size:13px;
background-image:url("http://s17.postimg.org/8y5rvkw3v/menu_bg.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is that kind of menu, I would advice to do that without any background image, but using just background-color and border-radius, I created a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xMZRT/

```
nav li {
    float: left; list-style: none; font-size:13px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

if you want that "gap" removed just remove the margin-right property i added.

Comment: IE 9.0 > should support it just fine. For more information you can refer to this: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your question.
But it seems to me, as if everything already works beautifully.
You just have to give your list items a width and height and… hey presto.

```
width: 154px;
height: 32px;
```

Okay, now you still have to adjust the padding and the width and height accordingly, but you get the idea.